# How to write a GET request in API Manager?

Tags: rest, wso2, wso2-api-manager, apache-synapse

I am trying to write the GET request for the search API. I am writing it like this `http://localhost:8280/solr/1.0/search?searchText=abc`, but I am getting a 404. If I'll write it as `http://localhost:8280/solr/1.0/`, I'm able to get the JSON response data.

I wrote it is as `/*` and getting the response using the URL `http://localhost:8280/solr/1.0/`.

If I am writing it as `/search*` I'm not getting the 404 (`http://localhost:8280/solr/1.0/search?searchText=abc`).

Where am I getting wrong?

Answer (score 0):

enable wirelogs and check what kind of request is sent from AM to Backend. You might be able to find out the reason for this. refer http://mytecheye.blogspot.com/2013/09/wso2-esb-all-about-wire-logs.html to enable and analyze the logs